# What power class does an iPad and an iPhone have?

Tags: iphone, ipad, power

I am doing antenna simulations in order to visualize the electric field produced by an iPhone and an iPad. In order to do so, I need to know what typical power output these devices have.

From Wikipedia it is said that:

> Whereas a mobile phone can range from 21 dBm (125 mW) for Power Class 4 to 33 dBm (2W) for Power class 1 [...]

I need to be more precise than this, so I was wondering if anyone knew what power class a regular iPad and and iPhone is?

Comment: The power output of a WiFi radio is regulated by Government.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radio frequencies and they respective power are regulated by official sources. In the USA, you will need to go to the FCC web site to get precise numbers for the radio power output.

In order to search the [FCC OET Equipment Authorization database](http://transition.fcc.gov/oet/ea/fccid/), you will need the FCC ID of the device you want to lookup.

All devices that use radio frequency spectrum are required to print their unique FCC ID on a label on the device.

It may also be printed on a separate document that accompanies the device.

Example for iPhone 4S WiFi radio.

[image: iPhone wifi power]